# How to rewrite an expression in order to have the result a multiple of X?

Tags: algorithms

I'm a programmer and need to create an algorithm that takes any expression and rewrite it in a way that the final result is a multiple of a specific value X.

For example, let's consider that i need to get the double of a value, so X = 2 in all cases below:

```
F1: 3 + 5 = 8
F1(x2): 3*2 + 5*2 = 16
```

In this example, my original expression is a simple sum and if i multiply all operands by 2 i'll get the correct result (8*2 = 16).

Here are other examples:

```
F2: 3 * 5 = 15
F2(x2): = (3*5)*2 = 30

F3: 3*5 + 4*5 = 35
F3(x2): (3*5)*2 + (4*5)*2 = 70

F4: 3+4+5+6 = 18
F4(x2): 3*2 + 4*2 + 5*2 + 6*2 = 36
```

So far my algorithm is simple: every add/substract operand can be multiplied by X, and every multiplication/division result too.

But for a complex expression like the following, my solution will not generate the correct result.

```
F6: (10 * (5*2) +3 * (4+ 4*2 +4) *2) *3 = 588
```

So, how could i rewrite the F6 function in order to get the result 1176. Is it achievable?

**EDIT**

This is for a report system on which i have rows for each department and subtotals, so i may have some values that cannot be multiplied if present, for example:

```
employees/10
```

The value of emplyoees is dynamic and already given to me by the database i'm using, for all rows of the table and the substotal is already calculated, so my table is something like this:

```
row_type    counter     company_name    department_name     employees   ten_percent     twelve
data        1           A               A1                  10          1               12
data        1           A               A2                  15          1,5             12
data        1           A               A3                  10          1               12
subtotal    3           A                                   35          3,5             12
data        1           B               B1                  10          1               12
subtotal    1           B                                   10          1               12
total       4                                               45          4,5             12
```

Where counter is the X factor i refer to. "twelve" is the formula "12", so multiplying it by counter would result ok, but for complex formulas that may have dynamic values it would fail. So i'm looking to a way to change the expression, if possible, to make it work on any scenario.

Thanks.

Comment: why not calculate the expression first and then multiply it by $2$. what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Vasya please see my edit, thanks

Comment: Why would you multiply _anything_ in that table by `counter`? For example, in the fourth row, where `counter` is 3, if you multiply `employees` by 3 you get 105, and now it is no longer the subtotal of the three numbers above it. But if you had a legitimate reason to multiply `employees` by 3, then it seems you _should_ do it for `employees/10`, since otherwise your "ten_percent" value will no longer be 10 percent of the number to the left.

Comment: It is hard for me to understand why we are performing a "magic inside expressions", when we are programmers, instead of isolating a function with the isolated right arguments (i.e. values to be doubled later in the "expression magic"), then calling this function with the doubled values...

Comment: Legacy stuff dan. Code is too complex at this point to change ths behavior. I'm trying different approaches to avoid rewriting too much code.

DavidK. Yes, i cannot simply multiply for the reason you said. My problem is that, from how it was implement so far,  employees column is calclated before ten_percent and twelve. I'm trying now to modify this approach, but this question is to know if is there a math way of rewrite the expression. That would solve my problem.

Thanks